# Remove the topmost key of an object?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to flatten or remove the topmost key of an object? For example:

```
const obj = {
  page: {
    title: 'x',
    images: {
      0: {
        src: '...'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I can get:

```
{
  title: 'x',
  images: {
    0: {
      src: '...'
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with `map` but the result isn't what I am looking for:

```js
const obj = {
  page: {
    title: 'x',
    images: {
      0: {
        src: '...'
      }
    }
  }
}

const x = Object.keys(obj).map((key)=>{
  return obj[key]
})

console.log(x);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have only a single property in the object?

Comment: What if there are duplicate keys in the 2nd level?

Comment: @Barmar no duplicate keys in the 2nd level. it is guaranteed

Comment: simply `const x = Object.values(obj)[0]`  or `const x = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,curr) => ({...obj[curr]}) ,{})`

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, it is a single property in the object. guaranteed. that's why it looks redundant.

Comment: You want to modify the existing object or create a new object?

Comment: @derpirscher modifying the existing object is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All current answers create a new object. This one will modify the existing one

```js
const data = {
  page: {
    title: 'x',
    images: {
      0: {
        src: '...'
      }
    }
  }
}

function flatten(obj) {
  let [k,v] = Object.entries(obj)[0];
  delete obj[k]
  
  Object.assign(obj, v);
}

flatten(data);
console.log(data);
```

If assigning to another object is also ok, this simple approach will work too.

```js
const data = {
  page: {
    title: 'x',
    images: {
      0: {
        src: '...'
      }
    }
  }
}

const flat = Object.values(data)[0];
console.log(flat)
```

Be aware, that neither of these approaches deepclones you data. And they both assume the structure of the original data is ok (ie it's an object with a single property at top level. And that property's value is a valid object itself)

Comment: Well, that depends on what you need. If you need to keep the reference to the original object intact but only flatten it, approach one is the way to go ...

Answer (score 5):

You could take the values and assign to a new object.

```
result = Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this by iterating the object keys.

Try this :

```js
let obj = {
  page: {
    title: 'x',
    images: {
      0: {
        src: '...'
      }
    }
  }
};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj = (typeof obj[key] === 'object') ? obj[key] : obj)

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this ..

```js
const obj = {
  page: {
    title: 'x',
    images: {
      0: {
        src: '...'
      }
    }
  }
};

const {
  page,
  ...flattenedObj
} = obj;

console.log(flattenedObj);
```

This uses object destructuring to create a new object (flattenedObj) without the 'page' key. The original object obj remains unchanged. The resulting flattenedObj will have the structure you're looking for:

```
{
  title: 'x',
  images: {
    0: {
      src: '...'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It sets `flattenObj` to an empty object. It's not getting the 2nd level, it's returning everything except the `page` property.

Comment: Have you tried executing this even once? First of all it sets `flattenedObj` to an empty object. Furthermore, it's not generic and assumes that the property to be removed is always named `page`